# Android File Chooser Return path to main class

Tags: image-processing, android-intent, bufferedimage

I want to implement an Android file chooser for OCR.

I have the source code from this site: [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/)

What I want is to create a main Activity using an intent to call the `FileChooser`

```
public class MainFileChooser extends Activity {
    Button btnBrowse =null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.utama);

        btnBrowse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBrowse);
        btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainFileChooser.this, FileChooser.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        });
    }

}
```

While the button is clicked it will be linked to `FileChooser` and then while a tile is clicked the activity will be returned to`MainFileChooser` and also return the file path.

The File Path will be processed for OCR such as converting to gray scale, features extraction and so on.

The Question is how can I return the image path to `MainFileChooser` activity and for the given path I can create bitmap image (buffered image)?

Comment: Consider using this one: http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/

Answer (score 1):

Like the source code for `FileChooser` suggested, you can modify `onFileClick` to return the image path:

```
private void onFileClick(Option o) {
  String path = o.getName();
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("path", path);
  setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
  finish();
}
```

Then, in `MainFileChooser`, instead of `startActivity`, use `startActivityForResult`:

```
setActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
```

You will also need to add `onActivityResult` to `MainFileChooser` to get the filename:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1234) {
     String path = data.getStringExtra("path");
     Toast.makeText(this, "Path: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```